# GPU can't allocate the DAG in a single chunk. Bailing?

Tags: mining, dag, ethminer

I decided to do solo GPU mining and set everything up (probably). Synced the blockchain, ran the Genoil 1.0.7 beta of ethminer on Windows. But I keep receiving this error:

```
Creating one big buffer for the DAG Allocating/mapping single buffer failed with: >clCreateBuffer(-61). GPU can't allocate the DAG in a single >chunk.Bailing. clEnqueueWriteBuffer(-38)
```

I used

```
export GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR=0 export GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE=100 export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1 export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
```

but to no avail. I am using Intel HD 4000 which has about 1.7/1.8 GB I guess. I reckon my Nvidia GT 620M is not enough. I am using Win 8.1 64bit. Any help please?

Comment: FYI: [Where do I see the current DAG size?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/13001/158)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't mine on an Intel integrated graphics. Also yes, you are correct your GPU has not enough memory to load the entire DAG file.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
ethminer.exe -G --list-devices
```

It will list openCL compatible devices.

You have to check that both MEMORY and MAX_ALLOC sizes are bigger than the current DAG (a bit more than 1.4 Gb at the moment).

On an Intel card it wouldn't surprise me that the MAX_ALLOC is too low even if the memory is ok.

A nice alternative is [Goldminer](http://goldminer.io/) which will automatically detect the issue if any and tell you how to solve it. Plus it has a GUI. And rebuilds DAG / restarts mining automatically.

Comment: "how to solve it." -> does this mean we can mine with a GPU of memory X GB when X is below DAG size?

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed DAG error with completely uninstall AMD Drivers and installation of 14.1beta custom setup - Display Driver only. The newer 14.12 also didn't work. So if you install good AMD display driver and nothing else (Control centers, etc.) - everything must work like it should.