# How to make mining efficient in terms of memory, for a light weight client?

Tags: blockchain, mining, light-clients, memory

Since mining is resource intensive process, how to make it more efficient for a lightweight client in terms of memory. I am ready for a trade off even it takes more time to mine than what it would take for a normal client.

Comment: Hi there. I'm sure others will provide better/more detailed answers, but the first thing to look at would be the DAG file. I'm pretty sure this is >1GB, and I'm also pretty sure it has to be this size to provide the ASIC-resistant memory hardness that makes ASIC-based mining implausible. As such, I think you may struggle to make a lightweight _miner_.

Comment: Hi sir. Since I am new to blockchain, can you guide me as  where to look for the resources for the same, like the details of DAG and ASIC-based mining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The simplistic answer**

For a mining client node, the best (i.e. smallest) memory footprint you could hope for would be dictated by the size of the DAG file. As the DAG file is currently [over 1GB](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13001/where-do-i-see-the-current-dag-size/13007) in size, and [will only get bigger](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/500/52), I don't think what you're hoping to achieve is currently possible.

---

**The DAG**

A DAG (a Directed Acyclic Graph) is a large dataset created by a version of the [Dagger-Hashimoto Algorithm](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/blob/master/Dagger-Hashimoto.md), and which is used by Ethereum's Ethash proof-of-work algorithm (i.e. it's directly used by miners).

More details: [What actually is a DAG?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/what-actually-is-a-dag)

It essentially provides memory-hardness, meaning that mining by ASICs, which are popularly used in Bitcoin mining, is no more favourable than mining with CPUs or GPUs.

More details: [By what mechanism are ASIC-based miners made less favourable?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33/by-what-mechanism-are-asic-based-miners-made-less-favourable)

Further details:

- [What's the best Hardware for Mining Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/whats-the-best-hardware-for-mining-ether)
- Ethash on the Ethereum wiki: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash

---

**Further investigation**

You could look into splitting up the DAG file into chunks. I believe this has been discussed in the past, but I don't know what came of it - others may know more about this. See issue [#2559](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/issues/2559) for a related discussion.